# Segmentation fault when trying to destroy sf::Font

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml, delete-operator, destruction

I am working with the SFML package and receive a segmentation fault when trying to close the window/program. I have located the line in my code that results in segmentation fault, which is when I try to destroy the `sf::Font` used for drawing text in the SFML window.

The line is simply:

`delete button_font;` (which is of type `sf::Font*`)

What I read from the SFML documentation, the `sf::Font` class does have a destructor. I also tested it right after defining the font object, it destructed itself as expected.

The font is loaded by `sf::Font::loadFromFile(~)`. It is used as argument by reference in some classes used as game states and menus. Could it be a problem that it is used by several `sf::Text` objects, when I try to delete the font?

Comment: Do you create the `button_font` using `new`? If not, you should not `delete`it either.

Comment: No, I did not think of that.

But it is stored as a pointer in a class variable. I though all pointers are to be destroyed properly by explicitly defined destructors? (I still have not grasped the proper use of constructors and destructors fully)

Comment: You can have pointers to non-dynamic objects too. Like `int i; int* p = &i;` where `p` is a pointer to `i`, but should not be `delete`'d.

Comment: I removed all unnecessary `delete` calls and let the end of scope handle the destruction of pointers not declared by `new`. it solved my initial problem. However, I am still using the wrong approach since (as I expected) my code leaks a lot of memory (checked with Valgrind).

I guess I should clear the "pointed memory" without ´delete´, but I am not sure in what way. Maybe with ´clear()´?

Thank you for helping out, despite the amateur mistakes.

Comment: Can you share the code example?

Comment: I found the problem, it was indeed that I was trying to `delete` a variable not created with `new`.

Comment: I can also add that sometimes I checked memory leaks with Valgrind over a remote desktop application (ThinLinc). When connecting to the schools at the university via this application, I had some minor memory leaks which I did not have when I ran the same code from the actual computers. The leak came from the application, not my code.

I have no idea why this happens, but in case someone else stumbles upon this it might be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers and dynamic memory is one of the tricky things in C++. There is many ways to fail, my guess would be that you deleted a pointer that you did not create with `new` in the first place or maybe you deleted it twice because two objects held a pointer to it.

While there *may* be a good solution for your direct problem, the *real* solution is using a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Comment: I did consider it. However, I want to learn how to use pointers the right way. I have used smart pointers before, and realize it's benefits. Therefore, for this project (I'm quite new to c++, I'm taking a university course on it right now) I want to use regular pointers. My new strategy is to create all pointers with `new` and free the memory with `delete` Being consistent, I should be able to avoid memory leaks and other problems.

Comment: its*

If anyone wonders, we did succeed using regular pointers. But as already stated, if it was a bigger project it would be more difficult to make sure all memory is cleared properly. I will probably never use that method again, but I learned a lot from it so I am glad I tried it.